# Creating dataframe in a function

Tags: r

How can I pass a function parameter when creating a data frame? E.g. if I have a function such as the below:

```
SampleFunction <- function(col_name){

  DF <- data.frame(col_name= character(0))
  DF

}
```

Running: `SampleFunction(col_name="Column_A")` does not resolve the col_name input. Should I be using assign here?

Cheers in advance for any advice!

Comment: What do you expect this function to do?

Comment: Do you want to extract a particular column from a data.frame ?

Comment: This is part of a longer function, with the col_name field having values added to it

Comment: So you want to create a data.frame with a single column, with the column name provided as an argument to the function? (Also wondering why you're assigning a zero-length vector to the column...)

Comment: Maybe `setNames(data.frame(character(0)),col_name)` but it is bad practice, I don't think you need to initialize like this.

Comment: Really easier to do something more like  `DF<-data.frame(character(0),character(0));names(DF)<-c(col_name1,col_name2)`